# failed connection with pdo file

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I try to code a project using PDO class and it fails on error

> "Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object"

I found some answers on stackoverflow but they didnt work and I dont know what to do now. I started try fix this 2 days ago and I still can not fix this. Please, if you know where is the problem, help me.

My config file:

```
//DB Params
define("DB_HOST", "localhost");
define("DB_USER", "root");
define("DB_PASS", "usbw");
define("DB_NAME", "talkingspace");

//define("SITE_TITLE", "Welcome to Talking Space");

//Paths
define('BASE_URI', 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/MVC/');

?>
```

And my PDO file

```
<?php class Database {
    private $host = DB_HOST;
    private $user = DB_USER;
    private $pass = DB_PASS;
    private $dbname = DB_NAME;

    private $dbh;
    private $error;
    private $stmt;

    public function __construct() {
        //Set DSN
        $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $this->host . ';dbname=' . $this->dbname;
        //Set options
        $options = array(
            PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,  
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
        );
        //Create a new PDO instance
        try {
            $this->dbh = new PDO($dsn, $this->user, $this->pass, $options);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->error = $e->getMessage();
        }
    }      
    public function query($query) {
        $this->stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($query);
    }  
    public function bind($param, $value, $type=null) {
        if (is_null($type)) {
            switch (true) {
                case is_int($value):
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_INT;
                    break;
                case is_bool($value):
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
                    break;
                case is_null($value):
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
                    break;
                default:
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_STR;            
            }
        }
        $this->stmt->bindValue($param, $value, $type);
    }    
    public function execute() {
        return $this->stmt->execute();
    }  
    public function resultset() {
        $this->execute();
        return $this->stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    }
    public function single() {
        $this->execute();
        return $this->stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    }
    public function rowCount() {
        return $this->stmt->rowCount();
    }    
    public function lastInsertId() {
        return $this->dbh->lastInsertId();
    }  
    public function beginTransaction() {
        return $this->dbh->beginTransaction();
    }      
    public function endTransaction() {
        return $this->dbh->commit();
    }
    public function cancelTransaction() {
        return $this->dbh->rollBack();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> it fails on error "Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object"

That's because you're calling the `single()` or `resultset()` method before the `query()` method. The correct order of statements should be like this:

```
$db = new Database();
$db->query("SELECT * FROM table_name");
$result = $db->single();  // or $result = $db->resultset();
var_dump($result); // to see the result set
```

**Edited:**

`name` is reserved keyword in MySQL. You should escape it using backticks. Always use backticks to wrap the table and column names and use quotes to wrap your strings. Backticks are only necessary when the table name or column name is a [MySQL reserved keyword](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html).

Your code should be like this: (`tested`)

```
class Topic { 
    private $db; 
    public function __construct() { 
        $this->db = new Database; 
    } 
    public function getAllTopics() { 
        $this->db->query("SELECT `name` FROM `users` order by `name` asc"); 
        $results = $this->db->resultset(); 
        return $results;
    }
}

$obj = new Topic();
var_dump($obj->getAllTopics()); // to see the result set
```

Comment: class Topic {
    private $db;
    public function __construct() {
        $this->db = new Database;
    }
    public function getAllTopics() {
        $this->db->query("SELECT name FROM users order by name asc");
        $results = $this->db->resultset();   
        return $results;
    }

I am not sure we understand ourself, but i think a dont call resultset before query method.

Comment: @MartinT_25 I've updated my answer. Please see the **edited** section of my answer.

Comment: thank you, but still not working. It fails on error "Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object". error is in database file in:
 
public function query($query) {
        $this->stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($query);  // here

Comment: @MartinT_25 I just tested your code on my local system and it's working fine. I don't see any other issue here.

Comment: could it be caused by any local setting ?

Comment: @MartinT_25 Sorry, I'm not aware of such local settings that could cause this issue. But this could be the connection issue. Make sure you're properly connected to the database. To debug the issue one last time, create a new php file, paste [this entire pastebin code](http://pastebin.com/9XZ9fVWE) on that file and run it. See what you get.

Comment: when I try to write php script with connection to database without pdo class everything works, but when i want to use pdo class it fails. I think its not problem of connection. My friend has just tested this code on his pc and it works. Which localhost do you use?

Comment: @MartinT_25 I'm running Wamp Server, version 2.5.

Comment: @MartinT_25 I just suggested you a method to debug the issue on your local system. What did you get?

Comment: If you mean create that php file with pasted code, yes i did that. Ok, I try wamp server, the same version and i will see what happen. Thank you for your time :-)